# How to closes a bootstrap modal in a react function

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have 2 modals that are opened in my react component after I update the date in the component the handleClose function is called and the modal closes. The problem right now is that only body of the component is disappearing, the modal header still shows. when I hit the modal close button it disappears[image: p]. My question is how would I close a bootstrap modal from a react function?

```
export default class Index extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      services: [],
      showHideNew: false,
      showHideEdit: false,
      editId: null,
      loaded: false
    };  
    this.hideComponent = this.hideComponent.bind(this);
    this.fetchService = this.fetchService.bind(this);
    this.handelClose = this.handelClose.bind(this)
  
   }

   
  componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchService()   
    }
    
  hideComponent(name) {
      switch (name) {
        case "showHideNew":
          this.setState({ showHideNew: true });
          this.setState({ showHideEdit: false });
          break;
        case "showHideEdit":
           this.setState({ showHideEdit: true });
           this.setState({ showHideNew: false });
            break;
      }
    }
  updateService(id) {
    this.setState({editId: id})
    this.hideComponent("showHideEdit")
  }
 
  fetchService = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/services`)
      const initialService = await response.json()
      const services = initialService
      this.setState({ services })
  }
  handelClose = () => {
    console.log("close here")
    this.setState({showHideEdit: false})
    this.setState({showHideNew: false})
   
  }


  
  render() {
    const { showHideNew, showHideEdit} = this.state;
    return (
      <> 
      <div>
      <div class="col-md-12 align-self-center text-right">
        
    <button onClick={() => this.hideComponent("showHideNew")} type="button" class="btn btn-grad" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal5">
    New Service
    </button>
    <small class="d-block mt-2"></small>

  
  </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 mb-5">
                    <h5 class="text-center mb-4">Services</h5>
          
                    <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Title</th>
                  <th scope="col">Tag</th>
                  <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                  <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
              {this.state.services.map(service => 
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{service.id}</th>
                    <td>{service.title}</td>
                    <td>{service.tag}</td>
                    <td><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal6" onClick={() => this.updateService(service.id)}>
                    <i class="ti-pencil"></i>
                    </button></td>
                    <td><button onClick={() => this.deleteService(service.id)}>
                    <i class="ti-trash"></i>
                    </button></td>
                  
                  </tr>
              )}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
             </div>

       <div class="modal fade text-left" id="exampleModal5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModal5" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Service</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          {showHideNew && <ServiceNew  closeModal = {this.handelClose.bind(this)} getService ={this.fetchService.bind(this)}  />}
          </div>
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade text-left" id="exampleModal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModal6" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit User</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          {showHideEdit && <Edit  getService ={this.fetchService.bind(this)}  services = {this.state.services} editId = {this.state.editId} closeModal = {this.handelClose.bind(this)}/>}
          </div>
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    
      </div>
      </>
     
    
      );
    
    }
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the original Bootstrap implementation of the modal. Do you have jQuery as a dependency for your project as well?

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 I do have jQuery

Comment: You generally would want to avoid using jQuery in a React project since jQuery usually mutates the DOM directly. If you have the leisure of switching out of a jQuery Bootstrap implementation then I recommend you look at [reactstrap's modal](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/) or [react-bootstrap's modal](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/).